# merge dataframes with timestamps and intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, timestamp

I have two dataframes.

df1contains number and timestamps. It is a very large set.

```
df1.head()
Out[292]: 
2016-08-31 08:09:00     1.0
2016-08-31 08:11:00     7.0
2016-08-31 08:14:00    90.0
```

df2 contains intervals

```
d2.head()
Out[292]:        
   start                 stop                         C
2016-08-31 08:09:00     2016-08-31 08:12:00         'a'
2016-08-31 08:13:00     2016-08-31 08:20:00         'b'
2016-08-31 08:20:00     2016-08-31 08:45:00         'c'
```

I would like to add a new column `C` to `df1` such that the value of `C` is corresponding to the value in `df2` for the interval which contained the index of `df1`.

Expected result

```
 df1.head()
    Out[292]:                      C
    2016-08-31 08:09:00     1.0   'a'
    2016-08-31 08:11:00     7.0   'a'
    2016-08-31 08:14:00    90.0   'b'
```

So far, I have tried:

```
 df1.loc[:,'C']=df1.index.map(lambda i:df2[np.logical_and(i>df2.starti<df2.stop)].C)
```

but it is extremely inefficient and crashes for some cases where there are values of the index which are missing from the interval list in df2.

How to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `IntervalIndex` by [`IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) first:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['start'], df2['stop'], 'both')
print (s)
IntervalIndex([[2016-08-31 08:09:00, 2016-08-31 08:12:00], 
               [2016-08-31 08:13:00, 2016-08-31 08:20:00],
               [2016-08-31 08:20:00, 2016-08-31 08:45:00]],
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')
```

Then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by new `IntervalIndex` set to new column by array created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
df1['C'] = df2.set_index(s).loc[df1.index, 'C'].values
print (df1)
                        A  C
2016-08-31 08:09:00   1.0  a
2016-08-31 08:11:00   7.0  a
2016-08-31 08:14:00  90.0  b
```

EDIT:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['start'].astype(np.int64), 
                                 df2['stop'].astype(np.int64), 'both')
print (s)
IntervalIndex([[1472630940000000000, 1472631120000000000], 
               [1472631180000000000, 1472631600000000000], 
               [1472631600000000000, 1472633100000000000]],
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[int64]')

df1['C'] = df2.set_index(s).loc[df1.index.astype(np.int64), 'C'].values
print (df1)
                        A  C
2016-08-31 08:09:00   1.0  a
2016-08-31 08:11:00   7.0  a
2016-08-31 08:14:00  90.0  b
```

Comment: df2.set_index(s) returns error: KeyError: ('datetime64[ns]', 'both')

Comment: This is a great solution, nice to know about IntervalIndex

Comment: @00__00__00 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: pd.__version__
Out[306]: '0.23.4'

Comment: @00__00__00 - I test it with pandas 0.24.0, last version. Is possible upgrade ?

Comment: your answer is correct and will be approved, but would you have a workaround for previous versions?

Comment: @00__00__00 - hmmm, possible solution should be convert datetimes to native format by `.astype(np.int64)` and apply solution.